# Is there a syntax to specify multiline code snippets in Google (Hangouts) Chat?

Tags: google-hangouts

I would like something like the Markdown options (of SO?), where

```
four leading spaces makes it look like code
blocks have been written
```

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Google (Hangouts) Chat only supports basic (not rich nor full Markdown) formatting. For your specific inquiry, use pairs of triple backticks, i.e.,

````
```
Hello
World
```
````

For this and other formatting directives, see either the [consumer help page](http://support.google.com/hangoutschat/answer/7649118) (for end-users), or the [format messages page](https://developers.google.com/chat/format-messages#format-texts) (for developers) in Google's documentation.

For those who are developers and **want to build Google Chat apps/bots**, I was part of the launch team back in 2018 and produced some video content to help you get started:

- Take a look at the [developer intro and Google I/O launch videos](https://developers.googleblog.com/2018/05/developing-bots-for-hangouts-chat.html). The intro shows you how to build (synchronous) bots that respond in real-time to user requests with an `@BOT` message.
- You can also write bots/apps that send alerts or notifications in an asynchronous manner. For information on how to do *that*, check out the [2nd developers video](https://developers.googleblog.com/2018/06/hangouts-chat-alerts-notifications-with.html).

Comment: And use `<Shift><Enter>` to put the newlines in - took me a while to work that out.

Comment: However, that's only true if you're typing verbatim. Most people cut-n-paste their code, so it's not necessary to do that for this scenario.

Comment: I paste my code in, but my code doesn't usually have the triple backticks around it - so I use `<Shift><Enter>` to put the triple backticks around the code I'm pasting in.

Comment: That's only if you need the extra line(s). I think I just ```<PASTE>``` and don't think about the extra NEWLINES.

Comment: I figured that the code snippet __MUST__ be plaintext. So when you copy and paste your code, make sure to paste plaintext without formating. For mac: `Command` +`Shift`+`V` should do the job.

Comment: This no longer works in 2024. The triple backticks block will only insert a single line, requiring your to scroll to the right to read a full block

Answer (score 15):

If it's a single line, you can use it between single back quote.

```
`Hello World`
```

Answer (score 3):

To include code, wrap it with triple backticks:

````
```
some
code
```
````

Ensure you paste as plain text. On Windows, you can use `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`V`.